# iPhone Navigation button previous button - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, navigationcontroller

I need to implement the back button; (as in webpages, when you click the `back` button the screen will set focus to the **previous** screen).

I am not using a navigation control here, instead i want to do this using a `Navigation bar` and then adding a `navigation button` on it. Now when the user clicks on the `navigation button` the previous `view` should be displayed.

How should i do this.

My screen looks like this :

When i click on Hello, it should go to the previous screen.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out [UINavigationController Class Regerence](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) then try something like this:

```
- (void)pickerCancel {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)doSomething {
    [myView.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel)] autorelease]];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
    [navigation setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [navigation setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
    [myView release];
    [navigation release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as that is its entire purpose.